# How to get CryptoJS result as hash_hmac PHP (SHA1)

Tags: javascript, php, hmac, cryptojs, hmacsha1

Try to genegarate HMAC on JS with CryptoJS lib from UTF8 string with UTF8 secret. Like PHP hash_hmac('sha1','...','...',true);

PHP :

```
$buf = ' accept';
$bufferedSecret = '��xDx�����4�J�?)#';

hash_hmac('sha1', $buf, $bufferedSecret, false);
/* d301cae776ed8c5d46ac93bd7441b01af4d1b888 */
hash_hmac('sha1', $buf, $bufferedSecret, true);
/* ���v�]F���tA��Ѹ� */
```

JavaScript :

```
var buf = ' accept';
var bufferedSecret = '��xDx�����4�J�?)#';

CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(buf, bufferedSecret).toString();
/* d301cae776ed8c5d46ac93bd7441b01af4d1b888 */
var forBase64 = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(buf, bufferedSecret);
CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(forBase64);
/* 0wHK53btjF1GrJO9dEGwGvTRuIg= */
```

How get same HMAC(SHA1) UTF8 value on JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was found a way for get UTF-8 RAW.

Used "convertWordArrayToUint8Array()" from here:
https://gist.github.com/getify/7325764
and just decode it.

```
var wordArr = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(buf, bufferedSecret);
var utf8Arr = convertWordArrayToUint8Array(wordArr);
var string = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(utf8Arr);
```